# Append search query to $http.get query in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, angular-http

I have had a few attempts at appending an order # entered as a search query to a $http.get url in my app, but with no joy.

If I put the full path of a specific order number it retrieves that order http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/121137

I added the search query on list.html in the controller as $scope.query = query;

```
 .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$cordovaBluetoothSerial', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $http, $state, $cordovaBluetoothSerial, $window, $location) {
      //$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/').success(function(data) {
      //$http({ url: 'http://example.com/api/booking/orders/', method: "GET", params: {query} }).success(function(data) {
      $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/+ $scope.query').success(function(data) {
          //$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/121137').success(function(data) {
          //$http.get('js/121137.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.orders = [ data.data ];
          $scope.query = query;
```

Here is the code in a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nc19DVjBWt7cepwMNCNH?p=catalogue). Any suggestions on more `$http.get` urls/syntax to try?

Comment: so you want to call `http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/+ $scope.query` when query field is entered . is that it?

Comment: Yes, I wish to add the search query entered on the list.html page to the $http.get url. At the moment it doesn't work, but if I add the full url manually in the controller it retrieves that order (http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/121137) so just need the correct syntax to enable order search to work for any order number I enter eg. 121137, or 121121 etc

Comment: `$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/'+ $scope.query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your controller executes the code

```
$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/'+$scope.query).success(function(data) {
  $scope.orders = [ data.data ];
  scope.query = query;
}
```

it will call `http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/` because `$scope.query` is undefined ( input box in list.html is empty). Now when you input something in the input box `$scope.query` value changes to the value in input box but the `$http.get..` will not get called as its not executed. instead enclose `$http.get` in a function like below

```
$scope.getOrders= function(){
  $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/'+$scope.query).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.orders = data.data;
  }
}
```

and list.html will be as follows

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" align-title="center">
    <h2 class="title">Order Search</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header ">
  <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" ng-model="query"  placeholder="Search Order #">

       <button ng-click="getOrders()">search</button>


      </label>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-show="query" ng-repeat="order in orders" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"
      href="#/tab/list/{{order.user}}">
        <h2>Product Name: {{order.name}}</h2>
        <h3>Quantity: {{order.seatcount}}</h3>
        <h2>Order Subtotal: £{{order.subtotal}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: That certainly makes sense and looks good, but doesn't work. i have edited your code slightly below(added bracket and $). Perhaps it is the code between ion-item that is not causing the order to list.  ```$scope.getOrders= function(){
             $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/'+$scope.query).success(function(data) {
              $scope.orders = [ data.data ];
              $scope.query = query;
              //console.log($scope.getOrders);

             })
          }```

Comment: I think we need $scope.query = query; in the function and then closing with ```})
}```

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw a single quote after $scope.query which is not should be like that cuz the JavaScript will see that is a String not parameter.

Just change this

```
$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/+ $scope.query').success(function(data)
```

To be this

```
$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/' + $scope.query).success(function(data)
```

It should work.